# Nature does not exist in my Eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am creating an customized eclipse plug-in and basis is Lua code. I want to build standalone IDE, so I have Application and LuaNature classes.

`plugin.xml` looks like this:

```
 <extension
       id="application"
       point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
    <application>
       <run
           class="com.my.ide.Application">
       </run>
    </application>
 </extension>
.
.
.

<extension
         id="id1"
         point="org.eclipse.core.resources.natures">
      <runtime>
         <run
               class="com.my.ide.core.LuaNature">
         </run>
      </runtime>
   </extension>
```

`Application.class` looks like this:

```
public class Application implements IApplication {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication#start(org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext)
     */
    public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
        try {
            int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor());
            if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART)
                return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;
            else
                return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
        } finally {
            display.dispose();
        }

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication#stop()
     */
    public void stop() {
        if (!PlatformUI.isWorkbenchRunning())
            return;
        final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
        final Display display = workbench.getDisplay();
        display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (!display.isDisposed())
                    workbench.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and `LuaNature.class` like this:

```
public class LuaNature extends ScriptNature {
    /**
     * Nature of IDE composed from plug-in ID
     * 
     * @return String
     */
    public static final String ID = Activator.PLUGIN_ID + ".nature"; //$NON-NLS-1$
}
```

When I run newProjectWizard for Lua Project, I get error

> Nature does not exist: com.my.ide.nature.

Am I missing some settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin.xml declares the nature to have the id `com.my.ide.id1` not `com.my.ide.nature`.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar issue.Seems to be you haven't defined nature id correctly. At this point your plugin being activating.So if project nature was configured

```
 <extension
         id="id1"
         point="org.eclipse.core.resources.natures">
      <runtime>
         <run
               class="com.my.ide.core.LuaNature">
         </run>
      </runtime>
   </extension>
```

Here **id** should be your project **nature id**. So use id which is given in **plugin.xml** as your project nature id.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your plugin might not be getting activated. I suggest you go to your Run/Debug Configuration dialog, select your configuration go to the plugins tab, make sure your plugin com.my.ide is checked and secondly click on validate to see if there are any missing dependencies once you know its checked. If that is the case try clicking add required dependencies. Once you are sure you have plugin included in the launch configuration and no dependencies are missing run the app again. If you are still have issues, go back to your launch configuration dialog and in the arguments tab add -console to the program arguments text area. Launch the application again and in your console type "start com.my.ide" to make sure there are no other errors that are causing your plugin from getting activated, if it starts okay then something else is the issue.